# MongoEngine ListField within a EmbeddedDocument throws TypeError on validation

Tags: python, mongodb, typeerror, mongoengine

I am not sure if it is a bug within MongoEngine or if I miss something.
I have the following Models set up:

```
class Features(EmbeddedDocument):
    version = FloatField()
    data = ListField(StringField)

class Article(Document):
    vendor = ReferenceField(Vendor)
    url = URLField()
    author = StringField()
    clean_content = StringField()
    features = EmbeddedDocumentField(Features)
```

When I test my models like this:

```
#add vendor
vendor = Vendor(name="techcrunch", config="vendor config")
vendor.save()

#create features
features = Features(version = 1.0)
features.data = ["5", "89"]

#add article
article = Article(vendor = vendor, url ="http://www.techcrunch.com", 
                  author ="MG Siegler", clean_content = "Apple rocks!")
article.features = features
article.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method _validate() must be called with StringField instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Can someone explain that?

EDIT:

Nevermind. I found my error.

It has to be:

```
class Features(EmbeddedDocument):
    version = FloatField()
    data = ListField(StringField())
```

Comment: You should post your answer and mark the question as answered!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the error.

It has to be:

```
class Features(EmbeddedDocument):
    version = FloatField()
    data = ListField(StringField())
```